# extracting every digit one by one from a string made out of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a file, this said file has x*y numbers like 12 rows and 21 columns 
from an external file, it goes like this

```
BufferedReader jack = 
              new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/root/Desktop/woop.txt"), 32768);
    //StringBuilder comfy = new StringBuilder();
    String   line = null;
    while ((jack.readLine()) != null) {
        line = jack.readLine();         


    }
    //System.out.println(comfy.toString());

    String[] strs = line.trim().split("\\s+");
    for (int fes=0;fes<511;fes++) {
        System.out.println("this is fes"+ Integer.parseInt(strs[fes]));
    }
    System.out.println("this is strs     " );
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            //System.out.println(jack.read());
            arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(strs[j]);
            //System.out.println("this is reader "+arr[i][j] + "  "+  i +"   " + j);
        }
    }

}
```

What I need is to get them in a multi-dimensional array lets say 
*arr*
when I call `arr[2][5]` and `arr[3][5]` I get 76 and 76 and I want 76 and 55 respectively

Comment: Could you clarify what your specific question is?

Comment: I am trying to get the numbers inserted in a certain row and column but it keeps repeating after the first row and column

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only use `j` for getting the string you want to parse, so you basically copy the first row of your array to all other rows.

You need to take into account the row you're supposed to be in, the formula for calculating the position in your input array `strs` would then be

```
(row number) * (length of one row) + (offset in row)
```

Or in your specific case you want to replace `parseInt(strs[j])` with `parseInt(strs[i*size2 + j])`

Comment: Also shouldn't line= be line+=?

Comment: @JeremyKahan Yes you are right, I completely overlooked that

Comment: two things first which line, second if I change it to i*size2 + j indexoutofbounds error occur

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that you are reading through the entire file in the while loop, but only saving the last line. Also, since `Jack.readline()` reads a line and moves on, you want to take care not to lose that line in the condition check of your while. You will have an easier time if you process each line as you read it. It could look something like this:

```
BufferedReader jack = 
          new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/root/Desktop/woop.txt"), 32768);

String   line = jack.readLine();
int rowNum = 0;
while (line != null) {
    String[] strs = line.trim().split("\\s+");
    int colNum = 0;
    for (String s : strs){
        arr[rowNum][colNum]=Integer.parseInt(s);
        colNum++;
    }
    line = jack.readLine();
    rowNum++;
}


}
```